# Unable to add/load Nginx subdomain (subdomain repeats)

Tags: nginx, subdomain

The long and short of it is, I've added a subdirectory to my code (/main-site/sub) and I wanted to add it to my nginx config. However, I can't stop the subdomain from loading incorrectly (some.web.site/sub/sub/index.html) loads instead of (some.web.site/sub/index.html).

Here is the config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site.com www.site.com ~^((?<subdomains>.+)?\.)?site.com$;

  root /srv/site;
  index index.html index.htm;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/site/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/site/error.log;

  if ($subdomains !~* "^(www)?$") {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://$subdomains.site.com/$1 redirect;
  }

  rewrite ^/(?!index)(.*).html$    $1        permanent;
  rewrite ^/stuff1$      /st1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/stuff2$      /st2 redirect;
  rewrite ^/stuff3$      /st3 redirect;
  rewrite ^/stuff4$      /st4 redirect;
  rewrite ^/stuff5$      /st5 redirect;

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to 404
    # hide html extension
    try_files $uri.html $uri/ =404;
  }
## Where this stays in or not the result is the same
## site.com/sub/sub/index and not site.com/sub/index
## location /sub/ {
##   root /srv/site;
## }

  # Redirect 404 to index
  error_page 404 = @fallback;
  location @fallback {
    rewrite  .*  / permanent;
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
rewrite ^/(?!index)(.*).html$    /$1        permanent;
```

I had to add a / before the $1.